# openURL returns false but app is opening successfully

Tags: ios, objective-c, openurl

Can anyone think of an explanation for a case where openURL returns false but the app is opened successfully?

```
NSString *appUrlPathStr = @"";
NSURL *appUrlPath = [NSURL URLWithString:appUrlPathStr];

if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:appUrlPath]) {
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:appUrlPath]) {
        NSLog(@"app opened");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"app not opened");
    }
}
```

Note: did not include the url string itself in the code here.

Comment: It would help if you updated your question with your exact code including the actual URL.

Comment: There you go, I added the code...

Comment: Did you test on a real device or in simulator ?

Comment: The real URL is probably the most important part of the question.

Comment: @rmaddy, please allow me to not agree with you on that. The URL is valid and works fine. I tested it using simulator & real device.

Answer (score 2):

I was not only having the same issue but to make things worse the other app would only open when it wasn't suspended or inactive (i.e. fresh start)

For me the problem was that I didn't add the custom scheme I wanted to query to my `Info.plist` file.

As soon as I added it to the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` entry the problems went away.

[image: query custom scheme]

For more info, see: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/querying-url-schemes-with-canopenurl/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Very interesting article. Thanks for the link, I did not know this particularity.

Answer (score 0):

**A logic explanation for what I have experienced:**

I checked the device logs and I notices that the app I am trying to open, shoots logs and get stuck way before it reaches the foreground. (moreover, it happens while the original app is in foreground).

Therefore, openURL hangs and reaches its timeout, then it returns false and the app I am trying to open eventually opens.

**Conclusion**, I need to check the app I am opening and see why it hangs before it becomes active.

Thanks everyone, and I hope it will help others.

Answer (score -1):

I have seen the same issue in iOS 7. My solution is:

1)

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
});
```

or

2)

```
[self performSelector:@selector(methodToRedirectToURL:) withObject:url afterDelay:0.1];
```